# Visual Studio Code extension for saving and reusing my own custom code snippets / boilerplate?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, boilerplate

I am looking for VSC extensions that will let me save my own code snippets and reuse them in any future projects with shortcuts like when I type `html` I am able to pick an option that generates whole document example that I can then continue modifying.

Ideally it should also have an option to export all custom settings so I can move them to another machine or back them up if I need to format the system.

I realized this was one of my major efficiency issues when I kept copying code from old projects to be reused in my latest work. I did check the extension search in VSC but so far only found such that already include existing snippet shortcuts.

Answer (score 3):

I found 1 viable method so far with native VSC but post if you know of an even better way.

Press `Ctrl + P` and `>` then type `Preferences: Configure user snippets` and then selecting a language. To generate json fast I used: https://snippet-generator.app/

It saves snippets in `AppData\Roaming\Code\User\snippets` folder so that is good for backuping or exporting.

To reorder snippets to have custom ones at the top of the suggestions box for faster use go to: `Workspace Settings > Text Editor > Suggestions > Snippet Suggestions` and set it to `top`.